# How do I annotate an objective c property with an objc_method_family?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

If I have a property named `initFoo`, how can I annotate it with objc_method_family(none) so that when I compile it under ARC it doesn't get a `Init Methods must return a type related to the received type` error:

`@property NSString *initFoo __attribute__((objc_method_family(none)));`

does not work and will return the cryptic `9 attribute only applies to void*` error.

Comment: Name the property differently.

Comment: In some cases (like automatic code generation) this isn't as easy as it sounds. There are other reasons why this name needs to stay as initFoo. I agree in principal that avoiding the name is probably the best course, but if you need it, I thought I'd show folks how you can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the property normally and then declare an accessor for it with the annotation.

`@property NSString *initFoo;`
`- (NSString *)initFoo __attribute__((objc_method_family(none)));`